# In-app purchase not working on App Store version

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

I added in-app purchase function to my iOS app. It works fine in the sandbox environment. However it doesn't work on the App Store release version. When I click the purchase button it just does not respond. So is there anybody who has the same issue? Or should I wait for some time until it is finally available?

The console output when I click the purchase button is attached below:

```
Aug 15 12:27:41 Android assertiond[66] <Notice>: [sushelper:9519] Attempting to acquire assertion for sushelper:9519: <BKProcessAssertion: 0x1004404b0; "SKProductsRequest" (finishTask:180s); id:\M-b\M^@\M-&4EFD024EF14B>
Aug 15 12:27:41 Android assertiond[66] <Notice>: [sushelper:9519] Add assertion: <BKProcessAssertion: 0x1004404b0; id: 9519-9599E024-F456-4E31-9CE5-4EFD024EF14B; name: SKProductsRequest; state: active; reason: finishTask; duration: 180.0s> {
    owner = <BSProcessHandle: 0x100434290; sushelper:9519; valid: YES>;
    flags = preventSuspend, preventIdleSleep, preventSuspendOnSleep;
}
Aug 15 12:27:41 Android assertiond[66] <Notice>: [sushelper:9519] Activate assertion: <BKProcessAssertion: 0x1004404b0; "SKProductsRequest" (finishTask:180s); id:\M-b\M^@\M-&4EFD024EF14B>
Aug 15 12:27:41 Android assertiond[66] <Notice>: [sushelper:9519] New process assertion state; preventSuspend, preventThrottleDownUI, preventThrottleDownCPU, preventIdleSleep, preventSuspendOnSleep (assertion 0x1004404b0 added: preventIdleSleep; removed: (none))
Aug 15 12:27:41 Android assertiond[66] <Notice>: [sushelper:9519] Setting jetsam priority to 10 [0x10108]
Aug 15 12:27:41 Android assertiond[66] <Notice>: [sushelper:9519] dump all assertions HWM:5 (CPUMON check): {
    <BKProcessAssertion: 0x10031a780; "Resume" (activation:inf); id:\M-b\M^@\M-&CEE99782A101> [active]
    <BKProcessAssertion: 0x1004404b0; "SKProductsRequest" (finishTask:180s); id:\M-b\M^@\M-&4EFD024EF14B> [active]
}
Aug 15 12:27:41 Android assertiond[66] <Notice>: Creating PowerAssertion on sushelper:9519
Aug 15 12:27:41 Android sushelper(UIKit)[9519] <Notice>: Failed to set (setSize) user defined inspected property on (UIActivityIndicatorView): [<UIActivityIndicatorView 0x159dbab60> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key setSize.
Aug 15 12:27:41 Android itunesstored(BiometricKit)[9048] <Notice>: identities: 0x0((null))
Aug 15 12:27:41 Android itunesstored(BiometricKit)[9048] <Notice>: identities: -> <private>
Aug 15 12:27:41 Android itunesstored(iTunesStore)[9048] <Notice>: ISStoreURLOperation: Sending headers for <private>:
<private>
Aug 15 12:27:41 Android itunesstored(CFNetwork)[9048] <Notice>: TIC Enabling TLS [80:0x104de0070]
Aug 15 12:27:41 Android itunesstored(CFNetwork)[9048] <Notice>: TIC TCP Conn Start [80:0x104de0070]
Aug 15 12:27:41 Android itunesstored(CFNetwork)[9048] <Notice>: Task <DB05DCF9-FA86-47CA-B82C-F8DF3C95C5AC>.<131> setting up Connection 80
Aug 15 12:27:41 Android itunesstored(CFNetwork)[9048] <Notice>: TIC TLS Event [80:0x104de0070]: 1, Pending(0)
Aug 15 12:27:41 Android itunesstored(CFNetwork)[9048] <Notice>: TIC TLS Event [80:0x104de0070]: 2, Pending(0)
Aug 15 12:27:41 Android itunesstored(CFNetwork)[9048] <Notice>: TIC TLS Event [80:0x104de0070]: 2, Pending(0)
Aug 15 12:27:41 Android itunesstored(CFNetwork)[9048] <Notice>: TIC TLS Event [80:0x104de0070]: 12, Pending(0)
Aug 15 12:27:41 Android itunesstored(CFNetwork)[9048] <Notice>: TIC TLS Event [80:0x104de0070]: 14, Pending(0)
Aug 15 12:27:41 Android itunesstored(CFNetwork)[9048] <Notice>: TIC TLS Trust Result [80:0x104de0070]: 0
Aug 15 12:27:41 Android itunesstored(CFNetwork)[9048] <Notice>: TIC TLS Event [80:0x104de0070]: 20, Pending(0)
Aug 15 12:27:41 Android itunesstored(CFNetwork)[9048] <Notice>: TIC TCP Conn Connected [80:0x104de0070]: Err(16)
Aug 15 12:27:41 Android itunesstored(CFNetwork)[9048] <Notice>: TIC TCP Conn Event [80:0x104de0070]: 1
Aug 15 12:27:41 Android itunesstored(CFNetwork)[9048] <Notice>: TIC TCP Conn Event [80:0x104de0070]: 8
Aug 15 12:27:41 Android itunesstored(CFNetwork)[9048] <Notice>: TIC TLS Handshake Complete [80:0x104de0070]
Aug 15 12:27:41 Android itunesstored(CFNetwork)[9048] <Notice>: Task <DB05DCF9-FA86-47CA-B82C-F8DF3C95C5AC>.<131> now using Connection 80
Aug 15 12:27:41 Android itunesstored(CFNetwork)[9048] <Notice>: Task <DB05DCF9-FA86-47CA-B82C-F8DF3C95C5AC>.<131> sent request, body N
Aug 15 12:27:42 Android sharingd(CoreUtils)[61] <Notice>: ### No BLE advertising address to generate auth tag
Aug 15 12:27:42 Android itunesstored(CFNetwork)[9048] <Notice>: Task <DB05DCF9-FA86-47CA-B82C-F8DF3C95C5AC>.<131> received response, status 200 content K
Aug 15 12:27:42 Android itunesstored(CFNetwork)[9048] <Notice>: Task <DB05DCF9-FA86-47CA-B82C-F8DF3C95C5AC>.<131> response ended
Aug 15 12:27:42 Android itunesstored(iTunesStore)[9048] <Notice>: ISStoreURLOperation: Received headers for <private>:
<private>
Aug 15 12:27:42 Android assertiond[66] <Notice>: Client relinquished <BKProcessAssertion: 0x1004404b0; "SKProductsRequest" (finishTask:180s); id:\M-b\M^@\M-&4EFD024EF14B>
Aug 15 12:27:42 Android assertiond[66] <Notice>: [sushelper:9519] Deactivate assertion: <BKProcessAssertion: 0x1004404b0; "SKProductsRequest" (finishTask:180s); id:\M-b\M^@\M-&4EFD024EF14B>
Aug 15 12:27:42 Android assertiond[66] <Notice>: [sushelper:9519] dump all assertions HWM:5 (deactivateAssertion): {
    <BKProcessAssertion: 0x10031a780; "Resume" (activation:inf); id:\M-b\M^@\M-&CEE99782A101> [active]
}
Aug 15 12:27:42 Android assertiond[66] <Notice>: [sushelper:9519] New process assertion state; preventSuspend, preventThrottleDownUI, preventThrottleDownCPU, preventSuspendOnSleep (assertion 0x1004404b0 added: (none); removed: preventIdleSleep)
Aug 15 12:27:42 Android assertiond[66] <Notice>: [sushelper:9519] Setting jetsam priority to 10 [0x10100]
Aug 15 12:27:42 Android assertiond[66] <Notice>: [sushelper:9519] dump all assertions HWM:5 (CPUMON check): {
    <BKProcessAssertion: 0x10031a780; "Resume" (activation:inf); id:\M-b\M^@\M-&CEE99782A101> [active]
}
Aug 15 12:27:42 Android assertiond[66] <Notice>: Releasing PowerAssertion on sushelper:9519 from update
Aug 15 12:27:42 Android assertiond[66] <Notice>: [sushelper:9519] Remove assertion: <BKProcessAssertion: 0x1004404b0; "SKProductsRequest" (finishTask:180s); id:\M-b\M^@\M-&4EFD024EF14B>
Aug 15 12:27:42 Android assertiond[66] <Notice>: [sushelper:9519] dump all assertions HWM:5 (CPUMON check): {
    <BKProcessAssertion: 0x10031a780; "Resume" (activation:inf); id:\M-b\M^@\M-&CEE99782A101> [active]
}
Aug 15 12:27:42 Android assertiond[66] <Notice>: -[BKAssertion dealloc] - <0x1004404b0>
Aug 15 12:27:43 Android CommCenter(libATCommandStudioDynamic.dylib)[80] <Notice>: QMI: Svc=0x03(NAS) Ind MsgId=0x0051 Bin=['01 25 00 80 03 04 04 5D 71 51 00 19 00 10 03 00 CD 07 00 14 06 00 C7 FC B0 FF 2C 01 A2 01 00 64 A4 03 00 01 64 00']
Aug 15 12:27:43 Android CommCenter(libCommCenterMCommandDrivers.dylib)[80] <Notice>: #I update
Aug 15 12:27:43 Android CommCenter(libATCommandStudioDynamic.dylib)[80] <Notice>: QMI: Svc=0x03(NAS) Req MsgId=0x006c Bin=[<private>]
Aug 15 12:27:43 Android CommCenter(libATCommandStudioDynamic.dylib)[80] <Notice>: QMI: Svc=0x03(NAS) Resp MsgId=0x006c Bin=[<private>]
Aug 15 12:27:43 Android CommCenter(libCommCenterMCommandDrivers.dylib)[80] <Notice>: #I sendNewThresholds: Updated thresholds
Aug 15 12:27:43 Android CommCenter(libATCommandStudioDynamic.dylib)[80] <Notice>: QMI: Svc=0x03(NAS) Req MsgId=0x004f Bin=[<private>]
Aug 15 12:27:43 Android CommCenter(libATCommandStudioDynamic.dylib)[80] <Notice>: QMI: Svc=0x03(NAS) Resp MsgId=0x004f Bin=[<private>]
Aug 15 12:27:44 Android atc(AirTrafficDevice)[3043] <Notice>: <ATLegacyMessageLink: 0x10319cf40, wifi=0> ---> [Ping Request. id=423, Session=0, params=(null)]
```

**UPDATE:** I tried the in-app purchase function on TestFlight and it works.

Comment: What does the console tell you?

Comment: @matt How can I get the console output of a App Store release version?

Comment: You can read the device's console in Xcode if the device is connected to the computer.

Comment: @matt I attached the console output. However I cannot figure out where the problem lies. The logs printed by 'debugPrint' seem to be missing...

Comment: My guess is that since the app hasn't actually been released and since it works in TestFlight, that's all you get for now.

Comment: So... What should I do now... Should I wait to see if it work after several days? I don't think it will be available over time...